# How to add a specific time for Volley Requesting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I am using multiple volley request in TabLayout, Tab1(1st req) and Tab2(2nd req).Problem is both requesting at the same time,which made App froze during swapping in TabLayout from Tab1 to Tab2.I want a specific delay,requesting the second.I hope you understood the scenario,feel free to ask more suggestions/clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt that the app is freezing due to sending a request through volley. 
Anyway if want to send the second request after the first request, put it in the response listener of first request like

```
JsonObjectRequest firstRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Send 2nd request here
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Handle Error case here            
        }
});
mRequestQueue.add(firstRequest);
```

If you want to send the second request after x seconds after switching to the tab 2, you can use `postDelayed` where you can detect the tab is changed (e.g., `onResume` if you are using fragments as tabs) like

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Your second request goes here
        }
    }, 
1000); //Will execute after one second.
```

For some advanced usages you can also configure request queue size of volley. For your specific scenario you can set number of maximum parallel request to one as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149453/volley-serial-requests-instead-of-parallel).