# I wants to hit 10 Volley API call one after another, how i can do this

Tags: android, android-volley

In my Application i wants to make volley API call 10 or more times, but i need to hit the request one after another, i am using for loop to make 10 request call,is there any option to hit the request in queue ?

Here is the code,

```
 for(int i = 0;i<10;i++) {

  serverAPICall();
}
```

Comment: `volley automatically manages queue for you`, When you add your request to queue .. isn't it ?

Comment: Hope this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/31603869/6414107

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volley - serial requests instead of parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149453/volley-serial-requests-instead-of-parallel)

Comment: @Saeavlnfern can you explain it in more details.

Answer (score -1):

I code in python... but there is sometimes a limit to the number of calls you can make in a given timeframe to an API (rate limit). Check the rate limit. If that is the case in this instance, you need to use a 'sleep' method to slow the loop down to get above the rate limit. Take a look at this solution:

[How to pause / sleep thread or process in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)